# OSGi performance debugging

Tags: java, osgi, embedded-linux

I am trying to diagnose a performance problem for a Java application which is built on top of OSGi. The platform is an ARM5 processor running on an embedded Linux box.  CPU utilization is frequently 100% with high memory consumption.

I'm on the embedded O/S side of the house, with the Java developers more skilled in Enterprise application development than Embedded. While my background also includes embedded Java, I've avoided OSGi for precisely this reason.

I'm looking for low-hanging fruit -- what are some common design errors that might be causing excess CPU and memory consumption that I could quickly investigate to get the CPU utilization back down to something far more reasonable.

Comment: We need more info; Which OSGi implementation are you using ? Felix ? Knoplerfish ? Equinox ? What JVM  implementation for ARM are you using ? Hotspot ? Java ME ? IBM J9 ? Also your problem probably needs profiling, not debugging.

Comment: I'll have to ask the developers about the OSGI implementation in use, but I suspect that's not even relevant -- this seems to be a problem that's independent of all the low-level details.  I think I know where some of the problems are -- this is a real time application and I suspect the Java code isn't addressing the timeliness of the data being requested and processed.

Comment: If you believe that the problem is something to do with OSGi then it is very relevant which OSGi implementation is in use... however I tend to agree that OSGi is not likely to be relevant. I would start by looking at lower level Java issues such as GC. Can you attach a profiler? If that is not supported on the real device, then can you run it on a desktop computer and profile it there? etc...

Comment: Neil, the developer did profile it on a Windows box and the largest memory hog was several thousand strings, all associated with OSGi bundles and their names.  That machine was too fast for the CPU contention to happen.  This is a 256MB ARM5 box and MB on top of MB of strings isn't exactly embedded Linux friendly.  I have access to some faster (400MHz), but still just as small on the memory, boxes and am toying with the idea of putting the application on one of them and seeing how much CPU it really wants, then profiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some common design traps, hope this helps:

- The creation of threads can be very "expensive". Do you have e.g. messaging that constantly creates new threads? Use a thread pool.
- same for objects (e.g. messages, measurements), especially heavy wrappers where only a single field inside changes. Use an object pool - it helps A LOT!
- Be very careful with strings, especially concatenation. Calling simple operations on strings (replacing, appending, copying) often involve the usage of many temporary objects “under the surface”, which has a negative effect both on memory and garbage collection. When modifications of strings are done in code which is executed very often (e.g. common methods of log helper classes, methods responsible for composing messages for sending over a protocol, etc.) then optimizations which replace the ineffective methods with implementations which don’t use temporary objects improve the performance significantly.

  - Use `StringBuffer`
  - Use own String parsing via `String.indexOf(int)` instead of `StringTokenizer` whenever possible
  - First char comparison via `string.charAt(0)` is faster than `String.startsWith(str)`
  - Use `String`’s equals method instead of `equalsIgnoreCase` whenever possible
- adjust the log level not to include debug messages during normal work. The simple creation of all these debug messages could slow down the system considerably. Also output to the console (even if you don't see it) usually slows down the system - always log to the OSGi Log service instead.

Comment: When the developer and I looked at the object dump, the strings were all created by OSGi.  That's why I have the feeling it's an OSGi problem.  I did see something else recently, and that was a number of ConcurrentModificationException's.  If objects are supposed to be removed from a Collection of some sort, and the exception is causing the object to get left behind that would explain a number of things I'm seeing.  As I said, I'm on the O/S side of the house, so it's a long stroll across the building to plotz in the developers cube.  And the embedded Linux crew has been busy for 6 weeks ...

Comment: Sorry for the late up-vote and acceptance.  In the long run, the software turned out to be unworkably bloated for the device and all of it was thrown out.  But the suggestions above are some of what was tried along the way towards trying to make it all work.

Answer (score 2):

You posted that the profiling showed a lot of Strings. So maybe you encounter an old Java performance trap.

If somewhere in your code you do: myString = myString + " "; or similar in a loop it will create a new object each time. In these cases it makes sense to use a StringBuilder instead. This is just a wild guess but it also hit me.

Comment: The strings all appear to be fixed content -- OSGi bundle names.  I was expecting to see what you described, so +1 for the suggestion, but I can't "^" your answer because it doesn't apply here :(

Answer (score 1):

Try out Knopflerfish, they have an open source framework implementation more focused on embedded. There is also a company Prosyst that has a commercial OSGi framework targeting embedded.